How to show that a convolution of function with the heat kernel can only improve its Holder regularity
Let $D$ be a closed connected set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $f\colon D\to\mathbb{R}$ be an $\alpha$-Holder continuous function. I want to show that if I convolve this function with a heat kernel $p_t$, then the Holder regularity of a new function is at least $\alpha$. That is, if we put
$$
g(x):=\int_D p_t(x,y)f(y)\,dy,\quad x\in D,
$$
then $\|g\|_{\mathcal{C}^\alpha}\le \|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^\alpha}$.
If $D$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}^d$, the result is immediate by change of variables:
$$
|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|=\Bigl|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (p_t(x_1,y)-p_t(x_2,y))f(y)\,dy\Bigr|=\Bigl|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} p_t(0,y)(f(x_1-y)-f(x_2-y))\,dy\Bigr|\le
 \|f\|_{\mathcal{C}^\alpha}|x_1-x_2|^\alpha.
$$
But what to do if the domain $D$ is an arbitrary closed connected bounded set? Then $p_t(x,y)\neq p_t(0,x-y)$ and the above argument does not work. Do boundary conditions matter here?
I am not sure how to prove this even if $d=1$ and $D=[0,1]$ with say Neumann BC.

Should $g$ be smooth because $p_t$ is in fact a smooth convolution kernel?

@LidingYao Yes, that's exactly my question. How to show that $g$ is smooth (at least $\alpha$-Holder continuous).

The heat kernel is the scaling of Gaussian (depending on t), which is smooth.

@LidingYao: you are correct if we are talking about the heat kernel on R^d, then everything is easy. But in my case the domain D is an arbitrary set (say $d=1$ and D is an interval $[0,1]$). Then the heat kernel is not a scaling of a Gaussian density.

Then that is a problem. What is the boundary assumption that you put on may change the result a lot.
